# get a list of currently running applications

Tags: android

I want to get a list of currently running applications like double click the home button on apple devices, or pressing the window button on android phones.

There were a few questions about this and the answers were to use 
    `getRunningTasks (int maxNum)`
or 
    `getRecentTasks (int maxNum, int flags)`

both of which were deprecated as of API 21
I tried to use 
    `getRunningAppProcesses()`, but this returns all the running processes including things like Keychain, inputmethods, sharedstoragebackup etc..

Is there a new way to only get the current apps running without all the android system things?

Comment: `window button on android phones`, where is it?

Comment: I don't know the actual name of the button, but on most phones there is a button that looks like two windows one behind each other

Comment: @vembutech that example uses the deprecated methods I mentioned, I'm interested in an alternative